# Refreshing custom view layout position

Tags: android, animation, layout, android-custom-view

I have to implement slidable menu in my app. User should be able to show/hide it by tapping on it and move left/right.

To implement this, I`ve created custom *SlidableFrameLayout* that extends *FrameLayout*. 
By overriding *onTouchEvent* method I calculate slide position and call

```
private void setLeftLayout(int left) {
    layout(left, getTop(), getRight(), getBottom());
}
```

to change position for *SlidableFrameLayout*. Everything works fine, but when I keyboard shows (after focusing EditText), *SlidableFrameLayout* changes its left value to 0, so if menu was closed, it becomes opened. The same thing happens when I hide the keyboard (generally, it appears in all actions that prevents calling layout methods, I think).

I can not invent how to fix it. Could you help me? If any additional info is required, I`ll attach it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result, I changed my logic:

```
private void setLeftLayout(int left) {
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = getFrameLayoutParams();
    params.leftMargin = left;
    params.rightMargin = -left;
    requestLayout();
}
```

In my case, view is a parent of FrameLayout, so I haven`t added any conditions in 1st line of the method. This method works pretty fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is related to calling layout directly. When the container view changes size as a result of the keyboard being shown/hidden onMeasure/onLayout will be called with the view's default bounds. In your case I'm guessing the left bound is 0, so layout is being called with 0 for left every time your window resizes.
Instead you probably want to use something like setTranslationX or scrollTo ..

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I tried it with scrollTo, but it`s not exactly what I need. I`ll try to use setTranslationX and notify about the results.